# Assets audio player

Tags: flutter, dart

when I try using assets audio player for play file extension .mp3 it show message like this "Cannot play assets/end_call_sound.mp3"

```
static void ringingSound() async {
    try {
      await assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Audio('assets/ringtone_default.mp3'),
      )
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      print('Error: ${error.message}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you show how you;ve define `assetsAudioPlayer`

Comment: Here brother  static final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

Comment: the path seems different `assets/end_call_sound.mp3`